# How does closure works in the below function

Tags: javascript, closures

I am new to closure concept. Can somebody explain me how closure works in the below function.

As per my understanding, function b() can access 'var y' if it is defined within A() and not under function a(). But it accesses the variable value though it is within another function.

```
function A(){
    function a(){
        var y = 'some text!!';
        return function(x){
            console.log(y);
        }
    }
    function b(someVar){
        var buffElem = [];
        someVar(buffElem);
    }
    var myFun = a();
    var mySecFun = b(myFun);
} A();
```

As per the above function,

```
myFun = function (x){
           console.log(y);
}
```

How does myFun understands what is y?

Comment: Still `b()` doesn't have access to `y`. The function just executes using `console.log()`.

Comment: In your example `b()` is not accessing `var y` only `a()` (and it's inner function) is. `a()` returns a function which is in the context of `a()`

Comment: @Fran: Can u explain in detail. So when we call b(myFun), it first executes a() and then remaining statements within b() function. That is var buffElem =[]; somevar(BuffElem). Is it?

Comment: Debug the code using `debugger` to see what gets executed when.

Comment: @Fran: Can u mention your above answer in the answer box. I will mark it as 'Answer to this question'